# SQL Linked Server - Queries failing

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I am trying to pass data to a linked server. In the event that the server is turned of both queries fail not  just the one on Server2.

```
INSERT INTO [Database 1].dbo.[TestTable1] ( [Text] ) VALUES ( 'TEST 1' )
INSERT INTO [SERVER2].[Database 2].dbo.[TestTable2] ( [Text] ) VALUES ( 'TEST 2' )
```

Is there an effecient way to gracefully allow things to be written to the local server even if the linked one fails?

Comment: Sounds like a good time to utilize [TRY/CATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: TRY/CATCH probably won't help at the same scope as likely this will be a compile time failure, in that case you would need to try the failure prone one in a lower scope with `EXEC`

Comment: Thanks guys but I tried the TRY/CATCH and both queries failed.

Comment: What does "both queries failed" mean? What error messages did you get?

Comment: OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SERVER2" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SERVER2" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
Msg 53, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].